# Logging operations in lightadmin

Tags: java, spring, logging, lightadmin

I have a Java web application which use Spring and Hibernate and I plan to use lightadmin to provide an administration interface.

However, I found very little information about the logging part of lightadmin : if I have such an adminsitration interface, I would like that any operation made to our data (such as create, update or delete) is logged in our custom logger (it's not on a file but on a table on the database, this choice has already been made and implemented long time ago).

My need is to have a log entry containing some information (might be just the id) about the modified rows. Is there a global way to configure it?

Or can I add a logging annotation somewhere in each class which extends AdministrationConfiguration? If yes, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class AbstractRepositoryEventListener like it's show on the LightAdmin documentation [here](http://lightadmin.org/getting-started/registering-repository-event-listeners/)

Add you logger insertion by overiding onAfterSave, onAfterCreate and onAfterDelete into your own RepositoryEventListener.

After you just need to register your listener like this

```
public class YourAdministration extends AdministrationConfiguration<YourObject> {

    public EntityMetadataConfigurationUnit configuration(EntityMetadataConfigurationUnitBuilder configurationBuilder) {
        return configurationBuilder
                .repositoryEventListener(YourRepositoryEventListener.class)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't thought about the listener... Thanks for your answer!